# Sonar - Null pointers should not be dereferenced - even though using a util method to check null

Tags: java, null, sonarqube, dereference

I am getting 'Null pointers should not be dereferenced' issue in sonar analysis on my code.

I know that below line of code can cause this issue.

```
 Student st = getStudent(id);
 System.out.println(st.getId()) ;
```

But in my case, i am adding a null checker from a util, as below:

```
 Student st = getStudent(id);
 if(!MyUtil.isNull(st)){
    System.out.println(st.getId(id));
 }


 public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
    if (null ==obj ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Still, sonar is showing the same error.

How to make sonar to understand my util method is doing the null check?

Comment: I don't think there is any way. But your util method is useless: it only obfuscates the code. Just use `if (st != null)` (or better: `if (student != null)`) which is more idiomatic, tells exactly what the condition is, and will probably allow Sonar to avoid that false positive.

Comment: Also note that your utility method could be rewritten as `return obj == null;`.

Comment: Additionally, using `if(x == y){ return true; } else { return false; }` is generally bad style. It's far cleaner to just do `return (x == y);`

Comment: Just like @JBNizet said, this code is much more complicated than it should be. It might be useful if you also post the relevant code from the Student class, as this might be a logical issue within that class

Comment: I am having same problem except that utility method also returns true if the string is empty i.e.  return (str == null || str.isEmpty()). So it is little more than simple null check.  Issue is Sonar/SonarLint is not able to do the static analysis correctly.

Comment: This is still an issue with the current Sonar version as well. I have a util method to check and perform various sanity checks on the response which I am getting from my downstream service call. Sonar does not see a null check performed within this util method and gives a null pointer dereference issue.